# Bootloader location, dual boot Ubuntu 14.10 & Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kubuntu, bootloader

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.10 on my laptop. I dual boot with Windows 8.1, and now I would like to install Kubuntu 15.04 alongside all this to see if KDE Plasma 5.2 + SDDM works with nvidia-prime or not.

My partitions currently look like:

- Main HDD:

  ```
  /dev/sda2 NTFS Windows partition
  /dev/sda5 Ubuntu 14.10 /
  /dev/sda6 Ubuntu 14.10 /home
  ```
- Secondary HDD:

  ```
  /dev/sdb1 empty ext4
  /dev/sdb5 Ubuntu 14.10 Swap
  ```

I want to install Kubuntu 15.04 on my `/dev/sdb1` partition.

Where should I put my bootloader during this installation, and why? When I installed Ubuntu, I set `/dev/sda` as bootloader location. Should I do the same now or will this mess up my current grub installation?

Answer (score 0):

Using /dev/sda should be fine , I think using anything else could cause problems.

As Kubuntu 15.04 is in testing i do recommend using a different computer , or if that is not an option using a VM for your testing needs , vmware player and virtualbox work great so far for ubuntu 15.04